# Next element in *entire* document after certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

This is a variation on a question asked so many times. Given any element, I want to be able to find any other element after it in the *entire* document. It can be a sibling but it could also be any other element that occurs afterward. For example, given the following markup,

```
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <div>
        <p>Foo</p>
        <p class="bar">Bar</p>
        <p>rawr!</p>
    </div>
    <p>bop</p>
    <input/>
    <div>
        <p>Another</p>
        <div>
            <span>something</span>
            <p>deep!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>last</p>
```

For the sake of this description, lets say the function I am looking for is called `$.fn.nextInDocument`. If I called:

```
$('.bar').nextInDocument('p'); //  <p>rawr</p>
$('.bar').nextInDocument('p').nextInDocument('p'); //  <p>bop</p>
```

Continuing on, it would get `<p>Another</p>`, then `<p>deep!</p>` and finally `<p>last</p>`.

Does something like this exist? I don't care if it is a selector or a function. I just need the functionality.

**EDIT** Updated the DOM structure to make it a more challenging question yet more clear for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? It's a generic solution that uses DOM methods to traverse nodes in turn and tests each against the jQuery selector.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PsEdZ/3/

```
(function($) {
    function nextNode(node, omitChildren) {
        var sibling, parentNode;
        if (!omitChildren && node.hasChildNodes()) {
            return node.firstChild;
        } else {
            sibling = node.nextSibling;
            if (sibling) {
                return sibling;
            } else {
                parentNode = node.parentNode;
                return parentNode ? nextNode(parentNode, true) : null;
            }
        }
    }

    $.fn.nextInDocument = function(selector) {
        var node = this[0], $node;
        while ( (node = nextNode(node)) ) {
            $node = $(node);
            if ($node.is(selector)) {
                return $node;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: this has held up to everything I threw at it so far. I wonder how well it performs, thought as of right now I am not planning on running in on excessively large pages.  thanks so much!

Comment: @Jeff: It could probably be optimized: for example, I imagine that evaluating the selector for every node is a cause of possible performance problems. I'd suggest only bothering to  do so if it's causing a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Not really sure it's useful, though...

```
;(function ($)
{
    $.fn.nextInDocument = function (s)
    {
        var self = this,
            next;
        do
        {
            next = self.nextAll(s).first();
            self = self.parent();
        }
        while (self.length && !next.length);

        return next;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/HAFn8/

Comment: @Matt Ball it has some issues going into child elements after a current element, although I am not sure if he was even after functionality like that: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/HAFn8/3/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. An obvious deficiency, it'll definitely make things more complicated if this is needed. Will need a better tree traversing algorithm.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this works but it looks promising. I put it in a fiddle and there is no way to match a selector. In other words `$('.bar').nextInDocument('p') == $('.bar').nextInDocument('div') == '<p>rawr!</p>`.

Comment: my requirements do need to traverse back down the tree again, however unfortunate that may be

Comment: @Jeff I do not understand what you mean by _"`$('.bar').nextInDocument('p') == $('.bar').nextInDocument('div') == '<p>rawr!</p>`"_

Comment: @Jeff exactly what is the definition of "next" that you have in mind?

Comment: @Jeff let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/969/discussion-between-matt-ball-and-jeff)

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(jQuery) {
jQuery.fn.extend({
    nextInDocument: function(a) {
        if (jQuery(this).next(a).length === 0) {
            //console.log($(this).parent().nextInDocument('p'));
            jQuery(this).parent().nextInDocument(a);
        }
        else
            return jQuery(this).next(a);
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thanks Boopathi. I'm not sure if I am missing something. I put this in a fiddle and your function returned the original element for each call, e.g. `$('.bar').nextInDocument('div')==<p>rawr</p>`. http://jsfiddle.net/jeffrod/nHeGU/

Comment: sorry about that ... corrected it .. check it .. has one more minor bug. ll improve ...

Comment: im getting nulls back from this. it still doesnt appear to work

Answer (score 1):

Here's a POJS version:

```
function nextInDocument(el, tagName) {
  var node, nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var start = false;
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();

  for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    node = nodes[i];
    if (!start) {
      if (node == el) start = true;
    } else {
      if (node.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
        return node;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: nice solution for plain old js. thanks. jquery can make use of more complicated selectors though which makes some other snippets more attractive to my particular situation.

Comment: Be careful of this approach, you may find performance issues if you make the selectors too complex. Consider using classes instead so that the next element is much easier to find.

Comment: good point. ill consider that if performance becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

take look at my code:

HTML

```
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <div> 
        <p>Foo</p>
        <p>Fooooo</p>
        <p class="bar">Bar</p>
        <p>rawr!</p>
    </div>
    <p>bop</p>
    <input/>
    <div>
        <p>Another</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p>last</p>

<a class="show" href="#">!!!</a>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    i = 0;
    start = 0;
    $('p').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('bar')) {
            start = i;
        }
        i++;
    });
    $('a.show').click( function(){
        alert($('p').eq(start+4).text());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mV8pm/

change `start+X` and you will get next 'p' tag

Comment: thanks. this seems like it is tightly coupled to the markup i gave in the demo, but i need something that can work "for any element" and grab "any element after it". i dont think this would be that flexible

Comment: i bet it will :) try it on different DOMs. all that you need is to put this code to JQ function. by the way, tag of start element (selected by class) and tags you are looking for after that should be the same (for example 'p').